# Making post request to server through angularjs getting error 404

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
.controller("HttpPostController", function ($scope, $http)
  {
 console.log('SendHttpPostData login', $scope.loginData);
    $scope.SendHttpPostData = function ()
     {
        var data = 
        {
            name:$scope.loginData.username,
            pwd:$scope.loginData.password

        }

        var config =
          {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
           }
        }

        $http.post('demo url', data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
         {
          console.log("  success"+status);

        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) 
         {

             console.log("  error"+status);

        });

    };
```

This is my code , I have called function SendHttpPostData() on 
ng-submit="SendHttpPostData()" in html file and added ng-controller in div properly than to i am getting 404 error whenever SendHttpPostData() is called,Please help me.

Comment: 'demo url' is not a valid url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it may help you. But you haven't defined demo_url.

```
var demo_url = 'http://facebook.com:8081';//whatever your url is    
$http({
        method: 'POST', url: demo_url, data: { name:$scope.loginData.username, password: pwd:$scope.loginData.password },
        transformRequest: function (obj) {
          var str = [];
          for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          return str.join("&");
        }
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config)
             {
              console.log("  success"+status);

            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) 
             {

                 console.log("  error"+status);

            });
```